# GCP App Engine use for non web applications

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a use case where I'd like to have an app running on GCP, with a schedule. Every X hours my `main.py` would execute a function, but I think I am in no need of having a web app or use Flask (which are the examples I've found).

I did try to use the function-framework, would this be an option within App Engine? (have the function-framework entrypoint as the entrypoint for the app)

Conceptually I don't know if the app engine is the right way forward, although it does look like the simplest option (excluding cloud function which I can't use because of the time restrictions)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to run some backend logic and then shutdown until the next run, cloud functions is done for that.

You can setup a cloud scheduler task to invoke the function on a time basis.

Make sure to keep the function private to the internet, as well as configuring a service account for the cloud scheduler to use with the rights to invoke the private function.

Be aware of functions configuration options to fit your use case  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring , as well as limits  https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits

Good turtorial to implement it: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/using-scheduler-invoke-private-functions-oidc

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the cloud function times out in 60s and my function takes about a half hour (data processing)

Comment: For longer processing a Cloud Run Job does the work. Setup is almost easy as a cloud function. 

You could also split your compute work by logic units, than have multiple jobs handling the units.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use a [Cloud Run Job](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs) (note that it's still in preview). As its documentation says

> Unlike a Cloud Run service, which listens for and serves requests, a Cloud Run job **only runs its tasks and exits when finished**. A job does not listen for or serve requests, and cannot accept arbitrary parameters at execution.

2. You can also still use App Engine (Python + Flask). Using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler), you schedule invoking a url of your web app. However, because your task is long running, you should use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers). Tasks allow you run longer processes. Essentially, you'll have a 2 step process

   a. Cloud Scheduler invokes a url on your GAE App.

   b. This url in turn pushes a task into your task queue which then executes the task. [This](https://nocommandline.com/blog/run-a-google-app-engine-app-which-uses-django-cloud-tasks-locally/) is a blog article (with sample code) we wrote for using tasks in GAE. It's for DJango but you can easily replace it with Flask.

Comment: Thank you. Option 2 is interesting, could I call multiple tasks in this manner? Call task #2 after task #1 has started but before it's finished?

Comment: Theoretically, you can call multiple tasks. It's just like opening multiple pages on a website at the same time. For your use case, your code needs to know that task 1 has started but it hasn't finished. Maybe task 1 writes something (e.g. Y) to DB as part of its exit. So, you kick off task 1 at X hour; you kick off task task2 5 minutes later (this ensures task 1 has started) and task2 checks for the presence of Y. If it isn't there, then it knows task1 hasn't ended and task2 starts

Comment: I am absurdly confused as to how a task with "regular code" (my data processing python code that takes 30min to complete) can live in the Flask application. All I see in the docs is how to add a task to a queue or https requests but nothing about the actual code to be executed.

Comment: In simple terms, Flask is a web framework i.e. it allows you to write code & the code is triggered by calling/visiting a url. You write your code (yourself) to address an issue & then you put it behind a url i.e. you're saying - to trigger my code, I have to visit www.XYZ.com/do_a/ to get the code to run. GAE says that when you visit any url (e.g. www.XYZ.com/do_a/), it must return an answer to the visitor within a max of 1 minute. Your code takes 30 minutes so this won't work. The work around is that www.xyz.com/do_a will submit a task at www.xyz.com/_do_b which can run for up to 1 hour